# How to add data to structures with a dynamic array in C?

Tags: c, struct, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

this is my first post on Stack-overflow, I hope I'm not posting a duplicate question but a I couldn't find any reference on this matter.
I have a "library management system" project in C, where I have to add books to the "library" by using an array of pointers pointing to the structures (books).
the problem is I tried a lot of things and nothing worked so far and last thing I tried gave me a lot of errors.

So basically I have this system in which there is a main menu, the user chooses an input to:
a. Add/return book
b. Take a book
c. Print books by times borrowed from the library
d. Quit

the rest of the options are easy to deal with if I understand how to add data into a structure.
my code so far looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BOOK_NUM 4
#define NAME_LENGTH 200
#define AVAILABLE 10
#define NOT_AVAILABLE 20

int menu_on=1;

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

typedef struct book {
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char author[NAME_LENGTH];
    int available;
    int times_borrowed;
} book;

book* Books[BOOK_NUM];

void AddBook()
{
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    printf("Please enter book name:");
    scanf("%s", name);
    for (int i=0;i<BOOK_NUM;i++)
    {
        if(name!=Books[i]->name)
        {
            Books[i]= malloc(sizeof(book));
            if((Books[i]=NULL))
            {
                free(Books);
                free(Books[i]);
                exit(1);
            }
            strcpy(Books[i]->name, name); // here is the problem**
            printf("Please enter author name:");
            scanf("%s", Books[i]->author);
            Books[i]->available=AVAILABLE;
            Books[i]->times_borrowed=0;
            printf("The book %s was successfully added!\n", name);
            break;
        }
        else if ((name == Books[i]->name) && (Books[i]->available==AVAILABLE))
        {
            printf("This book is already in the library :)");
        }
        else if ((name == Books[i]->name) && (Books[i]->available==NOT_AVAILABLE))
        {
            ReturnBook(name); //this function is for later.
        }
    }
 
}
```

what I'm trying to do is just add one book at a time, allocate memory for it, and then the rest of the details.
at most the "library" includes 4 books.

- available - if the book is borrowed or not (AVAILABLE/NOT-AVAILABLE)
- times_borrowed should be initialised when adding a new book since the new book is "never borrowed before"

The rest of the stuff can be done easily if I just know how to add these books and use the dynamic array with its content.

The error I receive is : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Comment: `if(name!=Books[i]->name)`  is not correct.  Use `strcmp` for string comparison.

Comment: Here, `name` holds address.

Comment: In addition to needing `strcmp()` with `if(name!=Books[i]->name)` -- just what do you think will happen if you have a lot of different books, and you start iterating over all of them overwriting the pointer to every book (with `Books[i]= malloc(sizeof(book));`) that doesn't match the one you are looking to store ?? You can only iterate over the number of books you have previously allocated for. `for (int i=0;i<BOOK_NUM;i++)` appears to iterate over all 4 pointers every time. Since `Books` is global, `Books[i]->name` will segfault for `NULL` values (most likely)

Comment: I really don't know, I still don't understand the concept that well. my code at this point is a disaster, all I'm trying to do is have a dynamic array and allocate memory specifically to the book that I need to add.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((Books[i]==NULL))
 {
    free(Books);
    free(Books[i]);
    exit(1);
 }
```

Here, you should use `==` not `=`. Using `=` will make `Books[i] = NULL`.

And use `strcmp` for string comparison.

Comment: Please see the `if` condition there. He is using `=` for comparison.

Comment: Aha, so far I fixed every detail that Krishna mentioned and fixed some stuff in my ```main``` and everything appears to work, it prints "The book {name} has been added" and return back to the main menu. is there anything else that I should watch out for?
I really appreciate your help.
thanks in advance for both of you :)!

Comment: @David  He is checking the condition after, `malloc `. So he is assigning NULL again after memory allocation.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula - I aplogize -- if this is the validation code -- then that is fine. You would actually want `while (i--) free (Books[i]); free (Books); exit (EXIT_FAILURE);`